# How to upgrade from Ubuntu-12.04 LTS to the latest Ubuntu version

Tags: 12.04

How to upgrade from Ubuntu-12.04 LTS to the latest stable Ubuntu version, could someone please help me with the procedure, can I find a KB article somewhere. ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As described by @George it takes a long chain of steps. Unfortunately the steps are risky (and slow), so I recommend that you **backup** your data files to another drive and disconnect it. Then you can create a **fresh installation** of the newest long time support (LTS) version or newest shortlife version of Ubuntu and restore the data files from the backup. It means that you have to install the special application programs that you need, but you can do it on the fly, when you need a particular program. I think it will give you a working new system much faster than upgrading from 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 8):

The steps has to be incremental viz:

```
12.04 to 14.04 to 16.04 to 16.10 to 17.04
```

Step 1:

1a. 12.04 to 14.04:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in "update-manager" (without the quotes) into the command box
- Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '14.04 LTS' is available.
- Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

1b. Server editions:

- Install the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed.
- Launch the upgrade tool with the command sudo do-release-upgrade.
- Follow the on-screen instructions.

Step 2: 14.04 to 16.04:

1. Make sure that you are fully up-to-date.
2. Trigger the update: `sudo update-manager -d`
3. The Update Manager application will open after a few seconds. It will double-check you're up to date. It will display a prompt asking you if you want to upgrade. Just click the “Upgrade’ button to begin the process.
4. Wait for for the update manager to finish its work.

Step 3:

1a. 16.04 to 16.10 (Desktop)

- First always backup important data, bookmarks, etc.

  - disable or remove all third-party repositories on Other Software tab.
  - select Open Source graphic driver in Additional Drivers and REBOOT after applied changes.
- Open `Software & Updates` using the Unity Dash
- Select the `Updates` tab
- Find the section titled `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version`
- Change this from `For long-term support versions to`For any new version`
- Click `Close`
- Run: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`
- Open terminal and run: `sudo update-manager -d`, when the `software updater` appears select `upgrade`

1b. 16.04 to 16.10 (Server):

- `sudo apt install update-manager-core`
- `sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

  - Change the line "Prompt=LTS" to "Prompt=normal" (without quotes) and save the file.
- `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Step 4 16.10 to 17.04:

1. Always make a backup of important data, bookmarks, and other user documents.
2. Remove or disable third-party repositories:

   - Launch Software & Updates utility, navigate to Other Software tab, and remove/disable all third-party repositories.
3. Restore to open-source drivers:

   - Also in Software & Updates utility, Additional Drivers tab, switch to the open-source drivers if proprietary drivers are in use. (Need restore after applied changes)
   - And it's better to choose download from 'Main Server' in Software & Updates utility.
4. Make your system up-to-date by running command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
   ```
5. After all, launch Update Manager via the command below and it will prompt that Ubuntu 17.04 is available after checking for updates:

   ```
   sudo update-manager -d
   ```

Source(s):

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-04-from-ubuntu-16-10/

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/upgrade-ubuntu-16-10-from-ubuntu-16-04/

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Comment: Thank you for your quick response George, I will try it on a development VM first before pushing this change to Production environment. Appreciate your help.